# Log python on Openshift

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have configured my Django project on Openshift with success.

But somewhere in my site I launch a command tool installed by **pip** and I think the command failed.
But I don't find python log with

```
rhc tail -a project
```

Or when I got to **/var/lib/openshift/*id*/app-root/logs/python.log** file I don't find more log than displayed at screen

**How can I see all my python output console ?**

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

I tried to use the [logging configuration for django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#examples), but I can't see my log even if I put my app name in **loggers**.

Comment: How do you do to read all your python log ?

Comment: I think I need to put the django logging ?

Comment: Nobody have issues on openshift for log ?

Comment: If anyone use django log on openshift can you explain me how to do !

Answer (score 1):

Your log files are at the directory specified by `OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR` environment variable. If you want to have custom log files, you should also write them there.

You can find more information on the log files here: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html

Comment: You're right the `OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR` environment variable is to custom the log path but for the DIRECTORY and not the file